# If laptop is in sleep and the battery gets critically low, will ubuntu put computer to hibernate?

Tags: 14.04, laptop, suspend, battery, hibernate

I know that on windows this happens, but I don't knw weather it works on ubuntu. So, the question is: *If laptop is in sleep and the battery gets critically low, will Ubuntu put computer to hibernate?*